# BeautifulSoup not returning source

Tags: web-scraping, beautifulsoup, urllib2

I am trying to download the table data from http://www.footywire.com/afl/footy/ft_match_statistics?mid=5634
but run into problems when I try and obtain the soup from BeautifulSoup

I am trying

url='http://www.footywire.com/afl/footy/ft_match_statistics?mid=5634'

soup=BeautifulSoup(url)

but just get back the header, or nothing at all.

I've also tried using different a different parser (html5lib), and also reading the page through urllib2, but still not getting any of the body of the page. I'm pretty useless at web interaction so maybe there is something fundamental I am missing, but it seems to work on other websites.

Any help would be much appreciated in pulling this data. Why am I not getting the expected source?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello fellow Aussie :)

I'd use requests and lxml if I were you. I think that website is checking for cookies and a few headers. Requests' session class stores cookies and will let you pass headers too. lxml will let you use xpath here which I think will be less painful than BeautifulSoup's interface.

See below:

```
>>> import lxml.html
>>> import requests
>>> session = requests.session()
>>> response = session.get("http://www.footywire.com/afl/footy/ft_match_statistics?mid=5634", headers={"User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_7_5) AppleWebKit/537.36","Accept":"text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8", "Referer":"http://www.footywire.com/afl/footy/ft_match_statistics?mid=5634","Cache-Control":"max-age=0"})
>>> tree = lxml.html.fromstring(response.text)
>>> rows = tree.xpath("//table//table//table//table//table//table//tr")
>>> for row in rows:
...     row.xpath(".//td//text()")
... 
[u'\xa0\xa0', 'Sydney Match Statistics (Sorted by Disposals)', 'Coach: ', 'John Longmire', u'\xa0\xa0']
['Player', 'K', 'HB', 'D', 'M', 'G', 'B', 'T', 'HO', 'I50', 'FF', 'FA', 'DT', 'SC']
['Josh Kennedy', '20', '17', '37', '2', '1', '1', '1', '0', '3', '1', '0', '112', '126']
['Jarrad McVeigh', '23', '11', '34', '1', '0', '0', '2', '0', '5', '1', '1', '100', '116']
... cont...
```

The xpath query could be a bit brittle, but you get the idea :)